# Should front end restrict list size or back end?

Tags: networking, language-agnostic

So I've got a list of objects which is processed in the backend side of my application and is then passed to the front end for displaying purposes. However, I only want to show 4 items from the list at most. My question is- should I clip the list in the back end or should I pass the whole list to the front end and allow it to clip the list?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the argument for you to do the second way? (For me, it would be clear to pass only the required data, but if you ask about it there must be some reasons for you?)

Comment: There aren't any restrictions as such.

Comment: then go with answer from victor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, on the back-end, to remove unneeded network transmission. You need do it once for all your front-ends.

I don't think there are practical use-cases when it's more suitable to do it on front-end, since, even if back-end doesn't trim and, thus, saves it's CPU a bit, much more processing is done by backend underlying OS to transmit redundant bytes to clients.